# Difference between "guardar" and "conservar"

Tags: verbos, significado, diferencias-entre-palabras

What is the difference between 'guardar' and 'conservar'?

They both mean 'to keep' and 'to preserve'.

Comment: There're some words in spanish that may be _ambiguous_ or with similar meanings. Without examples that you can provide, it will be difficult get an adequate answer for your question. A possible approach is find their meanings in a dictionary, you'll see there a clear meaning of each one of them.

Comment: Welcome to our site. We're glad you're here. I would like to encourage you to flesh out your questions a bit more. This question, for instance, appears to be easily answered by any Spanish dictionary. If you have consulted a dictionary, and remain with a question, please indicate this in your question, and explain the reason for your confusion over their differences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Spain, as a rule of thumb, people would use `guardar` for objects, tangible things. `Conservar` would be used for food or more abstract entities.

> He guardado mis calcetines en ese cajón.
>
> La comida se conserva mejor (se mantiene por más tiempo) si la guardas (metes/pones) en el frigorífico.
>
> Todavía guarda la medalla que le dio su madre hace 30 años.
>
> Lleva trabajando aquí 30 años y todavía conserva la ilusión del primer día.

There could be some exceptions to this rule of thumb, of course:

> Cuéntamelo todo. No te guardes ningún secreto.
>
> Este cuadro del Siglo X se conserva perfectamente. Posiblemente porque lo guardamos en uan bóveda aclimatada.

Even in some contexts you could use one or the other indistinctly.

> Tienes que guardar fuerzas para el último tramo de la carrera
>
> Tienes que conservar tus fuerzas para usarlas en el último tramo de la carrera
>
> Guardo buenos recuerdos de aquel viaje.
>
> Conservo buenos recuerdos de aquel viaje.

Answer (score 3):

From my 2 year experience in Mexico, those two are never used in the same context.

"Guardar" is used very frequently and it means "To keep" or "To put away" something.

> Me puedes guardar esto por favor? (Hasta que regrese)
>   Translation: Could you keep that for me please? (Until I come back)

"Conservar," on the other hand, means to "To keep/maintain something as is."

> Queremos conservar eso así. (Una regla, una ley, un artículo, etc.)
>   Translation: We want to keep that like it is. (A rule, a law, an article, etc.)

I hope this helps!

Comment: This is a great answer Robert. Welcome to Spanish.SE.

Answer (score 1):

From my perspective as a user (I'm Chilean), when the action does **not** involve maintaining something in good condition over time, then use only "guardar". For example, if your child socks are lying on the floor you would say:

> Hijo, por favor guarda tus calcetines. [Right]
>
> Hijo, por favor conserva tus calcetines. [Wrong]

But if your intention is to keep something "fresh" over time (food, memories, machines) you need use "conservar".

> Este líquido refrigerante te permite conservar mejor el motor. [Right]
>
> Este líquido refrigerante te permite guardar mejor el motor. [Wrong]

Extrapolating, we can say that *guardar* is to save in space, and *conservar* is to maintain over time. However, both words usually are synonymous when this distinction is not necessary, or considering that things which are conserved in time *also* saved in places.